# convert data in to correlation table R

Tags: r

I have some data that look like this:

```
gene1    gene2     col1        col2
gene_A   gene_A    1           1
gene_A   gene_B    0.000123    0.4231421
gene_A   gene_C    0.012931    0.1231233
gene_B   gene_A    0.123123    0.123123
gene_B   gene_B    1           1
gene_B   gene_C    0.1029381   0.12312
gene_D   gene_A    0.12312     0.154395
gene_D   gene_B    0.543534    0.123412
gene_D   gene_C    0.01293812  0.045983
...
```

On the final row, i'm not miswritting something. sometimes, there is no data for the correlation between some data. And I can't replace it.

How can I go from a data file that looks like this in to a correlation matrix where the values on `col1` will be the `upper triangular` and the values in `col2` will be the `lower triangular` part of the resulting matrix?

Comment: Jack can you show your expected outcome please

Comment: Please do show your expected output. For example, The presence of gene_A, gene_B (line 2) as well as gene_B, gene_A (line 4) does not make sense to me.

Comment: And maybe third try is the charm: please show expected outcome.